# In a Helm template, is it possible to merge values into a specific context or key?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am working on a Helm template where i want to reduce some repetitiveness in it, but not make the template reference every key in the spec for a certain resource type.

The resource I am working on at the moment is a Deployment. If I wanted to have full control of the deployment template from values, i could have something like this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
{{ toYaml .Values.deployment.metadata | indent 2 }}
spec:
{{ toYaml .Values.deployment.spec | indent 2 }}
```

Then a values file could have:

```
deployment:
  metadata:
    labels:
      appName: foo
  spec:
    selector: 
      matchLabels:
        appName: foo
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          appName: foo
      spec:
        <template spec goes in here, e.g. containers, etc>
```

The full deployment descriptor uses the same set of labels in multiple locations - at `metadata.labels`, `spec.selector.matchLabels` and `spec.template.metadata.labels` - this pattern is going to be the same for all the deployments i define using this template.

Is there a way to set up the template in a way that I can set labels once in values, and reference them in the template, but without needing to specify the full set of options that deployment spec specifies? e.g. I don't want to reference things like `strategy` in the template at the `spec` level, or include all the `spec.template.spec` keys in the template (like `affinity`, `containers`, and all the subkeys of containers)....

Would basically like to try run a `mergeOverwrite` but with specifying context of where to inject the labels....

here is an example of a values file I would like to use to render a deployment manifest:

```
deployment:
  name: myDeployment
  labels:
    appName: myDeployment
    otherLabel: foo
  annotations: 
    some.annotation: gets-added-to-metadata-annotations
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    strategy: 
      type: Recreate
    template: 
      spec:
        affinity:
          <affinity settings goes here>
        containers:
           <container spec goes here>
```

The template should inject `.Values.deployment.labels` into `metadata.labels`, `spec.selector.matchLabels` and `spec.template.metadata.labels`, but merge it with the rest of what was in values (e.g. the `.Values.deployment.spec` gets merged in as-is, and the template has no specific references to `spec.replicas` or `spec.template.<anything>`

Comment: The overall approach you're describing sounds a little bit more like what you might do with a tool like Kustomize, starting from a complete YAML file and trying to tweak it.  Do you need to make the entire Deployment and all of its objects deploy-time configurable; or can you put the bulk of the Deployment in the chart's `templates/*.yaml`, where you can use the Helm templating constructs?  You might look at the skeleton that `helm create` produces, which does have helper templates to fill in labels as you describe.

Comment: @DavidMaze - i came up with a way to do it, have posted the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by creating variables with a forced / specific context using `dict`.  My template looks like this:

```
{{- $labels := .Values.deployment.labels }}
{{- $selector := dict "selector" (dict "matchLabels" $labels) }}
{{- $templateSpecMeta := (dict "template" (dict "metadata" (dict "labels" $labels))) }}
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.deployment.name }}
  labels:
{{ $labels | toYaml | indent 4 }}
spec:
{{ mergeOverwrite $templateSpecMeta $selector .Values.deployment.spec | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

`$selector` is:

```
selector:
  matchLabels:
    <labels from values injected here>
```

and `$templateSpecMeta` is:

```
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      <labels from values injected here>
```

The above 2 are then merged in with the  rest of the spec from values at that context to give the result without needing to pass in each value of a deployment spec / subkeys, or having to repeat the label / matchLabel blocks.

The original values file I posted has been changed a bit, to only reference deployment stuff, and not have a whole `metadata` block in it any more.

```
deployment:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    appName: foo
    appType: bar
  spec:
    replicas: 2
    strategy: 
      type: Recreate
    template:
      spec:
        <template spec goes in here, e.g. containers, etc.>
        <the spec does not need template.metadata.labels>
```